# PhpStorm File open issue

Tags: phpstorm

I new to using PhpStorm, I am trying to figure out 2 things which are giving me issues:

1. When i have the phpstorm already open and i use windows explorer to open a php file i get a cannot find file error. If I close PhpStorm and try to open, it works fine. Any reason why it happens do I need to change any settings?
2. How do I view projects I created using phpstorm any feature similar to eclipse so I can switch and back between multiple projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. [It's a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-6745).
2. PhpStorm doesn't have workspaces concept, File | Reopen recent project is what you can use now.

Comment: are there any plugins which will help me view my projects ?

Comment: I am not aware of such plug-ins.